# Trying to update Primefaces charts within accordion

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to refresh Prime faces charts which reside in tabs on an accordion. When I click the button to update it only updates the chart which is in the currently open tab???

I am using Primefaces 3.0

```
<h:form id="content">
    <p:accordionPanel style="margin-top: 30px; background-color: white;">
         <p:tab title="Microsite and Multibrand">
             <p:lineChart id="dropoffChart1" value="#{gvBean.dropoffChart1.chart}"/>
         </p:tab>
         <p:tab title="Microsite and Multibrand">
             <p:lineChart id="dropoffChart2" value="#{gvBean.dropoffChart2.chart}"/>
         </p:tab>
    </p:accordionPanel>

    <p:commandLink actionListener="#{gVController.day}" update="content" title="day">
         <h:graphicImage styleClass="timeSetButton" value="day.png"/>
    </p:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. How did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding the attribute dynamic="true" to the accordian tag.